# Needs to understand passport.js local strategy

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, passport.js

I'm trying to add a phone in usernameField in passport strategy so users can also login using there phone number and email, but kinda stuck on how to do it after searching it on the internet - reading passport.js docs its not making any sense to me. 
Q1: Should I change my schemamongoose model or what as I can't add a third field in passport local strategy.

```
import  mongoose from 'mongoose';
import { Router } from 'express';
import Account from '../model/account';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import passport from 'passport';

import {generateAccessToken, respond, authenticate} from '../middleware/authMiddleware';

api.post('/register', (req, res) => {
  Account.register(new Account({
    username: req.body.email,
    phoneNumber: req.body.phoneNumber,
    myId: req.body.myId,
    termsandcondition: req.body.termsandcondition,

    verifiedEmailCode: uuid()
  }), req.body.password, function(err, account) {

    if (err) {
      return res.json({
                        "status": false,
                        "code" : 500,
                        "message": 'An error occurred: ' + err
                      });
    }

    passport.authenticate(
      'local', {
        session: false
    })(req, res, () => {
      // send email
      const confirmUrl = `${config.siteUrl}/api/v1/account/register/verifyemail?token=${req.user.verifiedEmailCode}`;
      gmail.sendMail({
        from: config.gmail.user,
        to: req.user.username,
        subject: 'Please confirm your email with Beamlive',
        html: `<a href="${confirmUrl}">Please confirm your email with mylive</a>`,
        auth: {
          user: config.gmail.user,
          refreshToken: config.gmail.refreshToken,
          accessToken: config.gmail.accessToken
        }
      }, (err, info) => {
        if(err) {
          console.log('error sending email', err);
          return;
        }
          console.log('successfully sent registration email');
      })


      })
      .then(message => {

      })
      .done();
      res.json({
                 "User":{"UserID": req.user.username,
                         "PhoneNumber": req.user.phoneNumber,
                         "myId": req.user.beamId.IdOne,
                         "termsandcondition": req.user.termsandcondition
                          },
                 "status": true,
                 "code": 200,
                 "message": 'You have successfully registered with  mylive'
      });

      });
    });
  });

  api.post('/login', (req, res, next) => passport.authenticate(
    'local', {
      session: false,
      scope: []
    }, (err, user, info) => {
      if(err) {
        return next(err);
      }

      if(!user.verifiedEmail && !user.verifiedPhone) {
        return res.json({ "status": false, "code": 403, "message": "You need to verify your email or Phone number" });
      }

      req.logIn(user, next);
    })(req, res, next), generateAccessToken, respond);

  return api;
}
```

//auth middle-ware:

```
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import expressJwt from 'express-jwt';

const TOKENTIME = 60*60*24*30 // 30 days
const SECRET = "server key will go here";

let authenticate = expressJwt({ secret : SECRET })

let generateAccessToken = (req, res, next) => {
  req.token = req.token || {};
  req.token = jwt.sign({
    id: req.user.id,
  }, SECRET, {
    expiresIn: TOKENTIME// 30 days
  });
  next();
}

let respond = (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).json({
    user: {userID: req.user.username,
    token: req.token,
    tokenTime: TOKENTIME},
    status: true,
    code: 200,
    message: 'User logged In'
  });
}

module.exports = {
  authenticate,
  generateAccessToken,
  respond
};
```

//Index.js:

```
app.use(passport.initialize());
let Account = require('./model/account');
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
  usernameField: 'email',
  passwordField: 'password'
},
  Account.authenticate()
));
passport.serializeUser(Account.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(Account.deserializeUser());
```

//Schema mongodb:

```
import passportLocalMongoose from 'passport-local-mongoose';

let Account = new Schema({

phoneNumber: String,
email: String,
password: String

Account.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);
module.exports = mongoose.model('Account', Account);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *passport-local-mongoose* library allows you to pass some options when adding the plugin, one of those options is *usernameQueryFields* which according to the docs:

> usernameQueryFields: specifies alternative fields of the model for identifying a user (e.g. email).

So in order to use the `phoneNumber` field, you should be able to do something like:

```
let Account = new Schema({
  phoneNumber: String,
  email: String,
  password: String
});

Account.plugin(passportLocalMongoose, { usernameQueryFields: ["phoneNumber", "email"] });
module.exports = mongoose.model("Account", Account);
```